# how to use variable from input and start shell script in Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

i have Electron app and want to get on click button values from input show alert message and and after clic `ok` on alert  execute shell command
I can get the values already and display `alert` but cant execute the script after

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");  //electron.remote.require

function getInputValue(){
            // Selecting the input element and get its value
            const name = document.getElementById("name").value;

            // Displaying the value
            alert("Continue" + name);


            exec("./shellscript.sh" + " " + name , (error, stdout, stderr) => {

                if (error) {
                    //console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
                    return;
                }
                if (stderr) {
                    //console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
                    return;
                }


               const data = (stdout);


               console.log(data)
            });
}
```

**UPDATE**

with @edemaine help comes out the shellscript is executed , but the script need good few second to give any output and looks like javascript is closing before the output , how can i delay the process, can any one help with solution , maybe add some loading bar ...
thank you

Comment: What is the error message you get? Do the other `console.log`s (including the commented out ones) print anything?

Comment: after alert ,is not printing anything.

Comment: What happens if you add a space as in `"./shellscript.sh " + name`?

Comment: actually there should be space (edited question already) , but still nothing

Comment: Perhaps you're just not seeing log messages? If you replace the `alert` call with `console.log`, do you see that output somewhere?

Comment: yes, i do , but just for a second

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235304/discussion-between-mar24n-and-edemaine).